# Hydrophobic, hydrophobized, or hydrophobicized?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, semantics, proper-nouns

I found three **adjectives** which can be used in the following context: "*velour (HYDROPHOBIC / HYDROPHOBIZED / HYDROPHOBICIZED) with alkenyl maleic anhydride composition*". Which one should be used, if any of them, in the sentence and what is the rule for it? It seems that the last two adjectives can be incorrect, but I am not sure if they are - I could not find the rules to sort it out. Also, what would be a **noun** which will describe the process of making surfaces hydrophobic?
I would appreciate if you could help me to find out more about correspondying rules for making similiar adjectives and nouns.

Comment: Hydrophobation is perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest "rabid", but I won't.

Comment: Only five syllables? Surely you can do better than that. How about “hydrophobicizated” or even better, “hydrophobicizalated”? The challenge is to do it in one syllable. The Anglo-Saxons might have said “oiled” (or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

> Velour, **made hydrophobic**…

The other examples are grammatically correct in the example sentence, but linguistic monstrosities that as a biochemist I have never encountered and which I would never tolerate from any student of mine or in any journal article I should ever referee.

But then, not everyone who has to publish in English actually speaks the language. My commiserations.

Answer (score 0):

From your question: "velour (HYDROPHOBIC / HYDROPHOBIZED / HYDROPHOBICIZED) with alkenyl maleic anhydride composition".

First, you are looking for a verbal phrase, not an adjective.

Speaking as a chemist, I can tell you that the right word is **hydrophobicized**, where **hydrophobicize** means "making a surface hydrophobic". Just what you would expect it to be based on the dictionary definition of *hydrophobic*, but you'll have trouble finding the verb in an ordinary English dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, Richard, for the explanation! The only word I used was "hydrophobic" so all other modifications sound strange to me. I will read more about verbal phrases and will try to find an advance English dictionary to look it up.

Comment: Thank God I gave up chemistry after my first degree.

Comment: @David MB was a good pick on your part, but as a MB you must also have the occasional terminology issue. :-)

Comment: I don’t do issues — except for children and journals. Some might say that’s my problem ;-)